How can I create a floating div which expands to the edges?
I want to create a navbar something like this: the name on the top left, and the div just to the right of that which expands to the right edge like it does normally if it wasn't floating. Here's a quick illustration:
                         \/margin
---------------------------|
     |-------------------| |
NAME | link1 link2 etc.  | |
     |-------------------| |
                           |
(whatever goes below)      |
---------------------------|

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make the div expand to the correct length while it's floating, it's more like this:
            \________/much larger than margin          
---------------------|
     |-----|         |
NAME | a b |         |
     |-----|         |
---------------------|

instead of
                   \/margin
---------------------|
     |-------------| |
NAME | a b         | |
     |-------------| |
---------------------|

The only way I can think of is to use padding-right somehow, but I wouldn't know how long it needs to be, especially with different screen sizes. I tried to use the padding-right just to give it a shot, but expectedly it didn't work when resizing the screen at all. Please help me, thank you.

You should add a snippet of your code so it's easy to proffer solutions.

You should really rethink your question, add some code that you have tried in order to solve your issue, then come back and rewrite your question if you have more issue. Have you looked into the concepts of flex-box? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox

You can make the navbar element fill the entire width, and make it a flex box. Then to the links div, you can give it a flex grow of 1.
This should get the job done. You wouldn't need to float any element.


#nav{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
}

#links{
  flex: 1
}




I changed it slightly, turns out I didn't need the width stuff if flex=1, but thank you! I had no idea the flex variable was a thing
